# ANGULAR 7 reload component view

Tags: angular

I want to reload a component view by clicking button icon, without refreshing the whole page.

My view code:

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    <div class="row" style="font-size: 2.125rem !important;">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        Tableau des Casiers 
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
        <nb-action icon="ion-refresh sizeicone" (click)="refresh()"></nb-action>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nb-card-header>

  <nb-card-body>
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" (custom)="onCustom($event)" [source]="source"
      (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)" (editConfirm)="onSaveConfirm($event)"
      (createConfirm)="onCreateConfirm($event)">
    </ng2-smart-table>
  </nb-card-body>
</nb-card>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In angular you don't need to refresh a component - angular will refresh page content automatically when it detects that variables, used on template, changes. So in `refresh()` method just update variables values. However if you really want to do it manually then you can use following construction:

template:

```
<my-component *ngIf="showComponent"></my-component>
```

ts file:

```
public refresh() {
   this.showComponent=false;
   setTimeout(x=>this.showComponent=true);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same trick, such as hackish style but it works

Comment: Good hack but sometimes you can see the component disappear/appear.